# How can you query a smart contract using the polkadot.js api?

Tags: polkadot, smart-contract, api, javascript

I want to query a smart contract which I deployed on the Aleph Zero testnet.
[The Polkadot.js](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/) documentation is pretty clear and easy to follow regarding connecting to the chain and querying general chain information. But I get a bit confused when it comes to querying information regarding deployed smart contracts.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
// Required imports
import { ApiPromise, WsProvider } from '@polkadot/api';
import { ContractPromise } from '@polkadot/api-contract';

// Initialise the provider to connect to the local node
const provider = new WsProvider('wss://ws.test.azero.dev');

// Create the API and wait until ready
const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider });
    
const contract = new ContractPromise(api, metadata, wasm);
```

I am a bit confused about what the metadata and wasm are in this context.
The documentation just sends me in a circle of links here.

Also, when I have established the connection to the right deployed smart contract, how can I query or execute methods to get information about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the Polkadot JS docs, I don't see where `wasm` is used tbh

```js
import { ContractPromise } from '@polkadot/api-contract';

// The address is the actual on-chain address as ss58 or AccountId object.
const contract = new ContractPromise(api, metadata, address);
```

But anyways, the alephZero docs also mention the following aspects in [this section](https://docs.alephzero.org/smart-contracts-tutorial/creating-your-first-contract#compiling):

> The resulting files will be placed in mytoken/target/ink/ folder. If the compilation is successful you will find there the following 3 files:
>
> - mytoken.wasm is a binary WASM file with the compiled contract
> - metadata.json containing our contracts ABI (Application Binary Interface)
> - mytoken.contract which bundles the above two for more convenient interaction with the chain explorer

So, once you compile your smart contract, and because you mentioned that you've deployed it, I assume you have a `metadata.json` file, which is the one that you have to add here `new ContractPromise(api, metadata, address);`

Instead of a wasm file, the third argument `address` is the actual address of your smart contract deployed on the testnet, its identifier.

So let's assume you have a directory `src` where you store the `metadata.json` file and the address of your smart contract is `5DewKiJMRAaeRuYH48wmyXiTwzxedkq6zziRNr2EmirZATK3`. You need to create the `ContractPromise` like:

```js
... //snip
// Create the API and wait until ready
const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider });
const scAddress = '5DewKiJMRAaeRuYH48wmyXiTwzxedkq6zziRNr2EmirZATK3';

const contract = new ContractPromise(api, 'src/metadata.json', scAddress);
```

Finally, in order to interact with your smart contract, you can follow this guide: https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api-contract/start/contract.read#reading-contract-values

Comment: I successfully loaded the contract. Thank you for your answer.
However, when trying to interact with the smart contract I always encounter this error.
"Uncaught TypeError: contract.query.balanceOf is not a function".
Do you have an idea what could be the reason for this?

Comment: If your smart contract does not have that function implemented, then it will throw that error. You can execute `queries` over your items defined under the macro`#[ink(storage)]`, but I'm not sure at all.

Comment: That was partially correct. I am implementing a PSP34 contract and it looks like you cannot query the methods implemented in the original PSP34 contract, but only the ones you defined yourself using #[ink(message)]