# Reading contract value returns null

Tags: ink, rust, smart-contract, substrate-front-end, javascript

Facing an issue while **trying to query for a value in my contract**. The value keeps getting retuned as null with an error. However, it works fine on substrate Contracts UI

**Front end Dapp :**

```
  const gasLimit = 3000n * 1000000n;
  // a limit to how much Balance to be used to pay for the storage created by the contract call
  // if null is passed, unlimited balance can be used
  const storageDepositLimit = null

  // Load the contract instance
  const Contract = new ContractPromise(api, abi, AlephsendContractAddress);
 
    // Perform a read of the contract's `get` message
  const callValue = await Contract.query.isPause("5HGn5UF5qdz8ShagwxRFSm387Hhd4wccAuVHZ17KtyyeUone",{
    gasLimit,
    storageDepositLimit,
  });
  console.log(callValue.output.toHuman());
```

**Contract function :**

```
#[ink(message)]
pub fn is_pause(&self) -> bool {
   
   return self.paused;
   
}
```

**This is how my storage is defined :**

```
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std, no_main)]

#[ink::contract]

mod aleph_send {

use openbrush::contracts::traits::psp22::{PSP22Ref,PSP22Error};
use openbrush::contracts::ownable::*;
use scale::alloc::vec::Vec;
use openbrush::traits::Storage;


#[ink(storage)]
#[derive(Default, Storage)]
pub struct Aleph {
    #[storage_field]
        ownable: ownable::Data,
        pub fee    : Balance,
        pub paused : bool
}



impl Aleph {...contract code}
```

**Any help would be much appreciated!**

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see what is wrong with your call, but let's try to fix it.

First be sure you have the proper metadata, see this previous StackExchange issue: [How can you query a smart contract using the polkadot.js api?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4161/how-can-you-query-a-smart-contract-using-the-polkadot-js-api)

You can try too if the result of the query has been ok like this:

```js
const { result, output } = await Contract.query.isPause("5HGn5UF5qdz8ShagwxRFSm387Hhd4wccAuVHZ17KtyyeUone",{
    gasLimit,
    storageDepositLimit,
});
// check if the call was successful
if (result.isOk) {
  // output the return value
  console.log('Success', output.toHuman());
} else {
  console.error('Error', result.asErr);
}
```

You have an example here: [Reading contract values](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api-contract/start/contract.read/#reading-contract-values) where it queries the [incrementer smart contract](https://github.com/paritytech/ink-examples/blob/main/incrementer/lib.rs).

And similar in this previous StackExchange Issue: [How to get output when calling a contract method and signing it?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4247/how-to-get-output-when-calling-a-contract-method-and-signing-it)

Comment: No luck. I even tried the out of the box example against the flipper contract and its still erroring out. How do https://contracts-ui.substrate.io/ do it? Doesn't seem to fail there

Answer (score 1):

`gasLimit` should be of type `WeighV2`, not `Weight`. Try something like

```
const gasLimit = api.registry.createType(
  'WeightV2',
  api.consts.system.blockWeights['maxBlock']
) as WeightV2;
```

For querying a method this should be sufficient. If you want to execute transactions than you need to query a method first to get gas limits.